# Nodejs and PassportJs: Redirect middleware after passport.authenticate not being called if authentication fails

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have no login page but rather I have a login form that appears on every page. I want to redirect user back to the same page they were on regardless of whether authentication was successful (with appropriate flash messages)

Take the following code:

```
app.post('/login', validateLogin, passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {

    var redirectUrl = '/'; 

    if(req.body.to.length > 0){
        redirectUrl = req.body.to;  
    }

    console.log("THIS IS ONLY CALLED IF passport.authenticate() IS SUCCESSFUL");
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
});
```

I only see the final middleware above being called if authentication is passed. If it fails then passport appears to be redirecting me to /login in the form of a get request. In my app this page doesn't exist.

If I pass an additional options object as a parameter in the passport authenticate function then this works:

```
app.post('/login', validateLogin, passport.authenticate('local-login', {

successRedirect : '/', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page. THIS IS JUST FOR TESTING TO SEE IF THE REDIRECT ON FAIL WORKS.
    failureFlash : true, // allow flash messages

}


));
```

But in doing this I lose the ability to choose where to redirect the user to. It seems that passport takes control over where the user is redirected to if authentication fails. How can I fix this? Or is it a bug? Must passport authenticate be the last middleware in the chain if authentication fails?

This is my local strategy function call:

```
//LOCAL LOGIN

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({ 
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form


    console.log("IN PASSPORT");

   if(email.length == 0 || password.length == 0){

       console.log("FIELDS ARE EMPTY"); 
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Fill in all values.'));

   }

    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else



        if (err){
            return done(err);
        console.log("db err");
        }
        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user){
            console.log("not user");
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Incorrect details.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
        }    
        // if the user is found but the password is wrong

        if (!user.validPassword(password)){
            console.log("invalid pw");
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Incorrect details.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
        }    
        // all is well, return successful user
        console.log("All OK");
        return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use a custom authentication callback as described in the last paragraph there http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    // Redirect if it fails
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      // Redirect if it succeeds
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: In your defense, it's a rather terse manual for a large concept. (coming across similar problems myself...)

Comment: Do we need to include 'local strategy' for that? In my case its giving me error of unknown local strategy.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same issue where the redirect-calls , that follow successful Facebook Auth

- ***passport.authenticate('facebook', ..)***

.. were not being honored.

Based on 'local' passportJS Strategy - and a nice reminder of that from [@ploutch's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22859331/2162226) .. I realized the key to getting it to work seems to be in this call:

```
req.logIn(user, function(err) {
 ...
}
```

For Facebook, this route setup worked for me:

```
app.get(
        '/auth/facebook/callback',

        passport.authenticate
        (
            'facebook', 
            { failureRedirect: '/fbFailed' }
        ),

        function(req, res) 
        {
            var user = myGetUserFunc(); // Get user object from DB or etc

            req.logIn(user, function(err) {

              if (err) { 
                req.flash('error', 'SOMETHING BAD HAPPEND');
                return res.redirect('/login');
              }

              req.session.user = user;

              // Redirect if it succeeds
              req.flash('success', 'Fb Auth successful');
              return res.redirect('/user/home');
            });      
        }
);
```

Comment: This one I don't understand.  If the passport.authenticate('facebook') middleware finished successfully and your next anonymous function gets called (that's the only way it could get called), then you would already be logged in and the req.login() call is redundant.

Comment: @TimHardy I found this type of structure very tricky/confusing myself; am not at all a fan of convoluted authentication constructs .. *grumble, grumble*.  For the solution here - the qualifying key words are *"this route setup worked for me"* :)

Answer (score 0):

Full answer, including:

- Middleware to set redirectUrl
- Flash messages
- Not returning values that won't be used

Just create a `redirectTo` value in your `loginRequired` middleware:

```
var loginRequired = function(req, res, next) {
    if ( req.isAuthenticated() ) {
        next();
        return
    }
    // Redirect here if logged in successfully
    req.session.redirectTo = req.path;
    res.redirect('/login')
}
```

And then in your login POST:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if ( err ) {
            next(err);
            return
        }
        // User does not exist
        if ( ! user ) {
            req.flash('error', 'Invalid email or password');
            res.redirect('/login');
            return
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            // Invalid password
            if ( err ) {
                req.flash('error', 'Invalid email or password');
                next(err);
                return
            }
            res.redirect(req.session.redirectTo || '/orders');
            return
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Just so I understand, you're not calling next with a success, which is what normally logs the user in with passport middleware.  You are instead calling req.login, which manually logs the user in, and you are implementing a custom redirect.

Comment: Yep Tim that's an accurate description. Maybe `.next()` is more idiomatic? What do you think? You're welcome to edit the post as long as the code works!

Answer (score 0):

I know this might still be a problem for some people like me who tried all the suggested options without any success.

In my case, as it turned out, I was getting the error because my req.body object was always empty. I had my body parsing middleware set up correctly so it didn't make sense why this was happening.

After more research I found out that the enctype I was using for my forms(multipart/form-data) isn't supported by body-parser - see their [read me](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#readme) - after switching to a different middleware, multer, everything worked smoothly.