# Express router skips a middleware entirely

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have an authentication route wired with PassportJS like this:

```
router.post('/',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  async (req, res, next, done) => { // Middleware 1
    console.log('FIRST MIDDLEWARE');
    const { body: { remember_me, username } } = req;
    // issue a remember me cookie if the option was checked
    if (!remember_me) { return next(); }
    const token = uuidv4();
    const tokenEntry = await new Token({ token, userId: req.user.id }).save();
    console.log('TOKEN ENTRY', tokenEntry);
    return next();
  },
  (req, res) => { // Middleware 2
    console.log('SECOND MIDDLEWARE');
    res.cookie(process.env.USER_DATA_COOKIE, signedUserData(req), {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
    });
    res.json({ success: true });
  });
```

But when run, the first `console.log()` never executes. Why? Shouldn't it get called before the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your passport.authenticate [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) calling direlctly done at the end of a function. 
So it will skip all the upcoming middlewares and directly runs your API callback function.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858699/nodejs-and-passportjs-redirect-middleware-after-passport-authenticate-not-being) will help you.