# Redirect to original URL after login in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, redirect, passport.js

I have a NodeJS server where some pages require logging in. At the moment, I have this code for login:

```
router.post("/login",
  passport.authenticate("user-otp", {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard",
    failureRedirect: "back",
  })
);
```

When I send a link to a user who is not logged in, they are redirected to a login page, enter credentials, go to a generic page, and have to go back to my message to find the original URL. I would like to condense the last two steps so users go to the original URL right after login.

Following [Send data back with the Passport js failureRedirect method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223723/send-data-back-with-the-passport-js-failureredirect-method?lq=1) , I tried the following:

```
router.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {
  let success = "/dashboard";
  if (req.query.redir) {
    success = req.query.redir;
  }
  return passport.authenticate("user-otp", {
    successRedirect: success,
    failureRedirect: "back",
  })
});
```

But submitting the login information does not get a response from the server, probably because I am new to NodeJS and the asynchronous logic.

**Update**: My passport function is:

```js
// Define the login strategy for users based on email and one-time-password.
passport.use('user-otp', new CustomStrategy(
  async function(req, done) {
    // logic...
    let user, email = req.body.email, is_email = false;
    try {
      
      user = await User.findOne({email});
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: "failed"});
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return done(err);
    }
    let check = await user.validateOtp(req.body.otp);
    if ("valid" === check) {
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
      return done(null, false, {});
    }
  }));
```

How can I redirect users to the original URL after login?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858699/nodejs-and-passportjs-redirect-middleware-after-passport-authenticate-not-being
If you haven't figured out yet, check out this thread.

Comment: That thread almost does what I want. When I implemented it, I realized that I needed to do it in GET parameters rather than in Express sessions because the user sign-up process happens in several pages. So I would lose the `req.session.redirect_to` in between. And I don't know how to pass GET parameters between middleware, authentication strategies, and the router. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is good but I think you should manually call passport, thats why you don't get any response from server.

```
router.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {
 let success = "/dashboard";
 if (req.query.redir) {
   success = req.query.redir;
 }
 return passport.authenticate("some-strategy", {
   successRedirect: success,
   failureRedirect: "back",
 })(req, res, next)
});
```

Comment: @miguelmorin can you provide some public example (github)?

Comment: I finally tried your code and it works out of the box. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First things first

> Following Send data back with the Passport js failureRedirect method , I tried the following:

> ```
> router.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {
>  let success = "/dashboard";
>  if (req.query.redir) {
>    success = req.query.redir;
>  }
>  return passport.authenticate("some-strategy", {
>    successRedirect: success,
>    failureRedirect: "back",
>  })
> });
> ```

the (passport)strategy in your code example in the question is `"some-strategy"`,

whereas your defined strategy name is `user-otp`.

If the real implementation is different than my description above, please update the question to reflect the correct code.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. I only have one passport strategy (when I started learning NodeJS, I couldn't figure how out to use two strategies) and I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
https://github.com/ne-cyber/login
```

see src/index.ts

```
app.get('/task', (req,res) => {
    if(login('GET', res, '/task', req.query, req.body)) {
        res.render('main.ejs', {
            queryObj: req.query,
            postObj: req.body
        })
    }
})
```

there is a simple function: `login()` if it returns true(token is valid or username&password is valid) and you may render your page. It saves query params and body(post) params